# Can I use the word "miscegenation" or "crossbreeding" to describe intelligent interspecies mating?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am writing a science-fiction novel where characters of one intelligent species can have sexual or romantic relationships with other intelligent species. Would it be appropriate to use the word *miscegenation* in this case? The standard Google definition specifies that miscegenation refers to

> sexual relationships or reproduction between people of different **ethnic groups**.

If not, is there a more appropriate neutral word?

I am thinking of *crossbreeding* but that sounds like it can only be used in the context of animals being bred by a third party for a specific purpose, as opposed to two intelligent beings voluntarily deciding to have romantic and sexual relations.

*Zoophilia* and *bestiality* do not fit here because they seem to imply sexual relations with a beast which is not a good neutral word for a highly intelligent species.

Comment: having sex is not breeding, cross or otherwise. :) Miscegenation is the result not the action. It means "mixing of different 'races' ". Brazil has a highly miscegenated population.

Answer (score 2):

**[Hybridization](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hybridization)** seems the most neutral term from zoology, botany, and animal husbandry. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_(biology)) says it can refer to breeding between different breeds, varieties, species, or genera (typically it is impossible to breed more distantly related animals).

All these terms have connotations; hybridization typically involves deliberate breeding to produce an offspring with different characteristics. It is used in botany/agriculture with this meaning, as well as when people breed lions with tigers, etc. Hence it contrasts with something like *miscegenation* which is often used by racists to condemn inter-race breeding.

*[Interbreeding](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interbreed)* is another term, but as Merriam-Webster mentions, it also has a different meaning, of breeding within a small population.

However if you are writing science fiction, you can choose your terminology freely, and may want to use a word with different connotations for a literary, moral, or satirical purpose.

Comment: having sex cannot be hybridization. The OP wants a word for sex.